# how to use global function in vuex action nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to use my global function in the Vuex actions

Let's see my code

//// plugin/global.js --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$roundDecimal = num => +(Math.round(num + "e+" + 2) + "e-" + 2);
Vue.prototype.$numberWithCommas = number => {
    if (number) {
        number = number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        number = number.replace(/\.00/g, "");
        return number;
    }
    return number;
};
```

//// nuxt.config.js --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
plugins: [
        {
            src: "~/plugins/global.js"
        },
]
```

//// store/order.js--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// mutations
SET_SHOP_LISTS_AREAS(state, _data) {
        let listsAreas = [];
        for (const areaItem of _data.areas) {
            listsAreas.push({
                id: areaItem.id,
                name: +areaItem.price
                    ? areaItem.name +
                      " ( " +
                      $numberWithCommas($roundDecimal(+areaItem.price)) + // <- there is error
                      " " +
                      this.getters["branch/getShopMonetaryUnit"](
                            _data.branch_id
                      ) +
                      " ) "
                    : areaItem.name,
            });
        }
        state.shopListsAreas = {
            areas: listsAreas,
            branch_id: _data.branch_id,
        };
    },
```

and i give error
[image]

Comment: Obviously that's not a global function but a method bound to the ``Vue`` prototype. You may call it via ``Vue.$numberWithCommas`` or just import it

Comment: `import Vue from "vue"; ` and `Vue.prototype.$numberWithCommas ` worked. but with this i have another question. if i use import vue here and use import vue another file , is it upload 2 times??